# Hide specific dropdown list values

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a dropdown list in my asp.net page which has a list of 10 items.  I want to hide some of these items from the dropdown so that the user cannot select them.  However, I want to initialise the dropdown control's value with one of these hidden items.  If the user doesn't touch the dropdown, then this  value will be valid even though it is hidden in the dropdown options.  On the other hand, if the user opens the dropdown then he cannot select a value that was hidden.

How would you go about this?  I tried setting ddl.Items[0].Enabled = false, but then I cannot initialise the control to this hidden value.  ie if it is hidden, the item cannot be selected not even programatically...

Comment: If the user changes the value from your default, then realizes they made a mistake and need to change it back, how do you want to handle it?

Comment: The scenario is this: The user creates records, selecting values from the list.  Through an admin screen, an admin user can mark items in this dropdown as obsolete so that they cannot be selected in new records.  When a user opens the old record with an obsolete value, it must be populated and remain valid, until he decides to change the value - in which case obsolete values will be hidden...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this code:

```
ListItem i = myDropDownList.Items.FindByValue("1");
i.Attributes.Add("style", "color:gray;");
i.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
i.Value = "-1";
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1132654.aspx